# How to deploy two different react apps with the same link

Tags: reactjs, hosting

I have created a code editor using Monaco editor which doesn't support mobile ports. I came across other editor known as Codemirror which supports the mobile port. I have created a code editor specifically for mobile port using Codemirror.

The problem is that these are two separate projects and I want to host them in such a way that when the link is opened in mobile it will show the Codemirror project and the same link will show Monaco editor in other device like laptop or PC.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to host the different projects in the same link.

Create a root component that will detect the device using something like `react-device-detect` and branch accordingly.